# How to Select-String with pattern that contains $value

Tags: powershell, select-string

How to search for a string that starts with $ in a txt file?

For example:

`Get-Content $file | Select-String -pattern 'VALUE="$USERPROFILE"'`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use the `[regex]::Escape()` method to correctly escape verbatim strings for use in regex patterns:

```
$pattern = 'VALUE="{0}"' -f [regex]::Escape('$USERPROFILE')
Get-Content $file | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
```

or use the `-SimpleMatch` switch to indicate you don't wanna use regex at all:

```
Get-Content $file | Select-String -pattern 'VALUE="$USERPROFILE"' -SimpleMatch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find strings that start with '$', you can use an approach similar to the one below.

```bsh
param(
    [string] $file = "$PSScriptRoot\test.txt",
    [string] $pattern = "$*"
)

$stringsBeginningWithPattern = (Get-Content $file).Split() | Where-Object {
    $_ -like $pattern
}

$stringsBeginningWithPattern
```